# How to make maven use a jar from local and not from remote repository

Tags: maven, jar, build

I have 2 maven projects **Core** and **Web** and Web is using the Core jar.

I made some changes to Core and I need to test it. So I built Core, installed the new Jar locally using `mvn install:install-file` - So now I have `core-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` in my local repository. and rebuilt Web.

The problem is that when building the Web project maven is using the Core jar from the company's build repository `core-0.1-<guid>.jar` and I dont see my changes. I tried to remove the `core-0.1-<guid>.jar` from my local repository and just leave the `core-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` but that does not help as well.

How to make maven pickup the SNAPSHOT version

Comment: What artifact id do you have in Web's pom.xml?

Comment: You might have configured core-0.1-<guid>.jar (Released jar) in pom.xml file of your web project. That's why it is pulling it from Jenkins.            Change it to core-0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar in pom.xml of your web project and you should be okay.

Comment: Sounds you like you need to use a multi module build to build the web and core within a single structure and not being separated.

Comment: I was hoping to find a better solution than changing every time the POM file. I guess for now this will do. Thanks